# How include a document with a documentclass in an another document

Tags: document-classes, include, yathesis

I write my thesis with the `\documentclass{yathesis}` and I must include my CV at the end of my thesis but my CV is in the `\documentclass{CV}`.

How can I include this CV in my thesis without problems of `documentclass` ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Perhaps the package `docmute` can help there

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You still can use `\includepdf` from `pdfpages` package:

```
\documentclass{yathesis}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf{CV.pdf}
\end{document}
```

*Note*: I do not have `yathesis` on my computer to test the code.

Comment: Toooooooooooooooo easy ;-)